# Plotly - adjust transparency of custom colour

Tags: r, plotly, visualization

I'm wanting to adjust the transparency/alpha of a line in a plotly chart.
I can't use `add_series`, as this chart is used in a Shiny app, with changing data, so the split must needs to be done on the `random_z` variable in the following data:

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(1)

x <- c(1:100)
random_y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
data <- data.frame(x, random_y, random_z = rep(c('A', 'B'), times = 50))

plot_ly(
  data, 
  x = ~x, 
  y = ~random_y,
  mode = 'lines',
  color = ~random_z,
  colors = c("A" = 'red',
             "B" = adjust_transparency('blue', 0.1)
             )
)
```

Color comes through without any transparency adjustment.
Changing the `adjust_transparency('blue', 0.1)` to `toRGB('blue', 0.1)` results in the error, "Error: Unknown colour name: rgba(0,0,255,0.1)".

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Plot with no transparency on blue series]

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop can be used in conjunction with `add_series` as well as a named vector that contains the colours, to achieve desired results.
(This works even if the underlying data changes - perfect for a Shiny app)

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(1)

x <- c(1:100)
random_y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
data <- data.frame(x, random_y, random_z = rep(c('A', 'B'), times = 50))

pal <- c(toRGB("red"), toRGB("blue", alpha = 0.1))
pal <- setNames(pal, c("A", "B"))


p <- plot_ly()

for(cols in unique(data$random_z)){
  p <- p %>% 
    add_trace(
    data = data %>% filter(random_z == cols), 
    x = ~x, 
    y = ~random_y,
    mode = 'lines',
    name = cols,
    line = list(color = pal[[cols]])
  )
}
p
```